# can't get my database to connect to my maths game

Tags: python, sql, database, user-interface

Basically I am trying to get my database to connect to my GUI and display a random question, however it is simply not working, any idea?

```
SQL = 'SELECT * FROM tblQuestion'
cursor = Databaseconnector.SELECT(SQL)
rows = cursor.fetchall()
rows = random.choice(rows)
print rows.Question, rows.Hint, rows.A1, rows.A2, rows.A3, rows.A4, rows.CorrectAnswer
#def create_widgets(self):
#create welcome label
label1 = Tkinter.Label(self, text = (rows(1).Question))
label1.grid(row = 0, column = 1, columnspan = 2, sticky = 'W')
```

> ERROR: TypeError: ‘pydodbc.Row’ object is not

Comment: I presume your error continues with "... is not callable"? This `label1 = Tkinter.Label(self, text = (rows(1).Question))` is the culprit and the reason is that `random.choice` returns a single row, but even if you have a list the proper way to do indexing would be `rows[1].Question`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rows` is first a collection of `pydodbc.Row` objects, but then you alter it to be a single `pydodbc.Row` object by calling random.choice:

```
rows = cursor.fetchall()   # rows is a list
rows = random.choice(rows) # now rows is a single object
```

Then you try to call that object using `()`:

```
label1 = Tkinter.Label(self, text = (rows(1).Question))
```

which fails with the error message you provided (partially):

```
ERROR: TypeError: ‘pydodbc.Row’ object is not callable
```

---

The best way to solve this to use a new variable for the single row:

```
rows = cursor.fetchall()   
random_row = random.choice(rows) 

...

label1 = Tkinter.Label(self, text = (random_row.Question))
```